# update column in all rows with column set to null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a column with null values in a table to something else. This is what I thought it should be, but it's not working.

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `column_name` = 'new value'
WHERE `column_name` IS NULL;
```

edit:

Hmm, it did end up working. I was using phpMyAdmin to "Simulate query" and it told me my syntax was wrong and to look it up in the mysql manual. After ignorning the warning and just clicking "Go" it updated as expected. sorry for the bother.

Comment: Why it's not working? what's the end result? It should work BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your column value may be an empty string, not `null`. There is a difference.

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `column_name` = 'new value'
WHERE `column_name` IS NULL
OR `column_name` = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the value you are assigning to the column is correct. If you have a int and are trying to assign a string it will not work.

Create a new column with the propert NOT NULL and default it to whatever you want. Then copy the values from the old column into the new column where they are not null. You will now have a new column with the values from the old column. The old column can be dropped. I have experienced this issue is the column sometimes contains corrupt data.